# Application cache manifest chunked

Tags: cakephp, caching, manifest, chunked

I have this cakephp manifest method in my controller that dynamically creates a manifest file. Thank to `$this->RequestHandler->setContent('manifest', 'text/cache-manifest' );`, I can set the MIME type correctly, and everything worked.

Now the problem is that my manifest file has become very large, it contains a lot of lines, and finally its dimension reached about 72Kb, and this caused the file to be split in two or more chunks when downloaded, and the final file is read as an text/html and not a cache-manifest anymore!

This is what a header sniffer told me, infact:

Small version of manifest:

```
HTTP Response Header
Name Value  Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/cache-manifest; charset=UTF-8    
Date:   Wed, 26 Jun 2013 14:23:34 GMT   
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.10 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10    
Content-Length: 843 
Connection: Close
```

while with the large manifest:

```
HTTP Response Header
Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:   text/html   
Date:   Wed, 26 Jun 2013 14:05:23 GMT   
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.10 
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.3.10  
transfer-encoding:  chunked 
Connection: Close
```

At what level do I have to change things to solve this problem? Apache level? Php/Cakephp level?

Answer (score 0):

### Use the response class

Normal responses from cakephp don't handle chunked requests - that's something that ordinarily only applies to downloads/static files.

You can however write your response to a file, and then use [sendFile](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) to send the response which will honor chunked requests as it would for any asset.

### Or let Apache do it

Alternatively, write the cache manifest to the webroot on deployment (or on first request) and let apache take care of it. Your responsibility then would only be to ensure the file's contents are updated when necessary (as determined by your application logic).